# WebService cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, web-services, class

i'm having a bit of a problem developing an android app. but somehow i get the error "WebService cannot be resolved to a type". i already installed the Android SDK Tools with my Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. do i need to install any other software?

thanks
ads

Comment: when i used it in the class i created. i type: WebService webService = new WebService(my_url); then it gets highlighted in red. when i put my mouse over it then i get the error.